# how do i convert tabs to spaces on many files with bash

Tags: bash, tabs

How can I convert tabs to spaces in in all .js files in a directory in one command?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -iname "*.js" -print0 | xargs -0 -I _FILE_ tab2space _FILE_ _FILE_
```

Answer (score 1):

This would convert tabs to four spaces:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -iname '*.js' -exec sed -ie 's|\t|    |g' '{}' \;
```

Change the space part in sed between the next two `|` to have a custom number of spaces you like.

Another way is to process all files to one sed call at once with `+`:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -iname '*.js' -exec sed -ie 's|\t|    |g' '{}' '+'
```

Just consider the possible limit of arguments to a command by the system.

Comment: @theUnknown777 The latter executes `sed` only once and passes all found files to it as a single set of arguments while the former would execute `sed` for every file.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler syntax:

```
for F in *.js; do sed -iE 's|\t|    |g' $F; done
```

(Caution, edits files in place.) Could be made to rename edited copy, or placed into a function if you do this often.