# What's the difference between `\;` and `+` at the end of a find command?

Tags: bash, find, command-line-interface

These are bash commands that are used to convert tabs to spaces.
Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18469894/2925306) to the original stackoverflow post.

This one uses `\;` at the end of the command

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -iname '*.js' -exec sed -ie 's|\t|    |g' '{}' \;
```

This one uses `+` instead of `\;`.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -iname '*.js' -exec sed -ie 's|\t|    |g' '{}' '+'
```

What exactly is the difference between the two?

Comment: `\;` isn't a bash command. It is equivalent to `";"` and it is specifying `;` as an argument (to find, not bash syntax).

Comment: Please take a look at sections `-exec command ;` and `-exec command {} +` in find's manpage.

Comment: @Cyrus - thanks, i don't know what to look out for in the manpage of `find` to find how they differ thanks.

Comment: @user2864740 i'm kinda new to bash, so i guess it's specific to `find` command?

Comment: On another note, to convert from tabs to spaces, or vice-verse, you could better use [`expand`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=expand) utility. You can also specify tabsize for expand. Advantage: for tabsize=4, consider a line beginning with `<space><tab>A` (note that there is a leading space before the first tab). Your `sed` command will replace tab to 4 spaces, making 'A' to be in 6th column counting from 1. Correctly, A should be in 5th/9th/13th etc column, if it is immediately after a tab. `expand` handles it properly by changing `<space><tab>` to `<4*space>` in above example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `\;` or `+` is not related to bash. It's an argument to the `find` command, specifically to `find`'s `-exec` option.

`find -exec` uses `{}` to pass the current file name to the specified command, and `\;` to mark the end of the the command's arguments. The `\` is needed because `;` by itself *is* special to bash; by typing `\;`, you can pass a literal `;` character as an argument. (You can also type `';'` or `";"`.)

The `+` symbol (no `\` needed because `+` is not special to bash) causes `find` to invoke the specified command with multiple arguments rather than just once, in a manner similar to `xargs`.

For example, suppose the current directory contains 2 files named `abc` and `xyz`. If you type:

```
find . -type f -exec echo {} \;
```

it invokes the `echo` command twice, producing this output:

```
./abc
./xyz
```

If you instead type:

```
find . -type f -exec echo {} +
```

then `find` invokes `echo` just once, with the following output:

```
./xyz ./abc
```

For more information, type `info find` or `man find` (if the documentation is installed on your system), or you can read the manual online at http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/

Comment: thanks i finally understood the difference between them.